# how to preset a dropdown list in reporting services?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report done in reporting services with some drop down lists. What I want to do is preset one of these lists so that when the report runs, it is automatically selected. How can I do this? Whenever I run the report I have to select an item from the list otherwise it won't let me run it.

Can you help me?

Thank you!!

I add screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to set default values. These can either be from a dataset or manually set. Read here for more info 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-change-or-delete-default-values-for-a-report-parameter?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: In fact I have made a default value but what I am looking for is that, when running the report, this value is automatically selected. That's what I don't know how to do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Default values are selected automatically that's the whole point of them. Edit your question and add some screen shots of what you have so far and where you see the problem. Also, remember that your defaults values must be the value part of the parameter not the label (if they are different)

Comment: It should be noted that in that drop-down list I have a dataset and a default value. I want this value to appear by default but also have the possibility of changing it for some of the values ​​returned by the dataset.

Comment: I added screenshots

Comment: I usually add another column to the parameter's dataset for the default value. You need to create logic to determine the default value and then add it as another column (Code_Default?) to all of the records in the current parameter's dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that you set the default value to a valid value. The value must appear in the field stated in your available values 'value field' .

So in your case the string `"TODOS"` must appear in your `Code` field in the `DS_Sector` dataset.

I suspect you either need to select the Code for "TODOS" or if `TODOS` is a valid `Code`, remove the quotes from the default value.

Comment: The item "TODOS" appears and is included in the DS_Sector query. It actually works. But what I want is that, when raising the report, it is automatically preset in "TODOS" without the user having to select it from the list.

Comment: That is exactly what I have described. Have you confirmed that "TODOS" INCLUDING the quotes is actually in the Code field of your dataset? If this does not help, add the output from the DS_Sector dataset query in your question.

Comment: It worked!! Thanks a lot! I put TODOS without quotes and it worked. 
Thank you very much for the information.